# unique_ptr in structure inside vector doesn't compile when resize used on vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, visual-c++-2010, unique-ptr

VS2010

I have a structure that has a `unique_ptr` inside.  I then have a `vector` of this structure.  If I try to resize (or use reserve on) the vector, I get compilation errors.  Below is a stripped-down example that still exhibits the problem.

```
struct Test
{
    unique_ptr<int> pValue;
};

void test()
{
    // this doesn't compile
    vector<Test> testVector;
    testVector.resize(5);

    // this also doesn't compile
    testVector.reserve(5);

    // this, of course, compiles
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> testVector2;
    testVector2.resize(5);
    testVector2.reserve(5);
}
```

The errors I get are complaints about accessing private members of `unique_ptr` (the assignment operators).  The compiler is trying to dynamically construct `Test &Test::operator =(const Test &)` and `Test::Test(const Test &)`.  I don't see why a resize operation would need to call either of these functions (why doesn't it just call the default constructor if it needs to?).  Both of them present problems because it isn't possible to make either with `unique_ptr` due to the `const`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate to interrupt this conversation you're having with yourself. :-)

But the answer is that VS2010 does not yet fully implement the C++11 spec (which would require a bit of time travel).  `Test` should have a defaulted noexcept move constructor that calls the `unique_ptr` move constructor.  VS2010 does not implement this implicit `Test` move constructor.  If it did, your complete example would compile and run as expected.  `vector` will use noexcept move constructors to move things around when it needs to.

Comment: I appreciate the interruption! :-) I never would have guessed that the problem was that V10 (and now VC11) do not implement `noexcept`.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Answer (score 0):

*(another case where writing out and posting the question led to the answer)*

The answer, of course, is that `unique_ptr<>` doesn't have copy semantics.  Even so, I was able to use the above arrangement right up until I needed to call `resize()`.  What I didn't think about is that `resize()` potentially has to move the block and the items within to another memory block.  That's when the copying happens.  Even though it is only extremely temporary, it still violates the uniqueness of `unique_ptr<>` during the copy.

What further confused me is that since `unique_ptr<>` doesn't have copy semantics, `vector<unique_ptr<>>` shouldn't work either.  But the answer must be that a template specialization has been written for this case.

I could probably write a template specialization for `vector<Test>` as well that would avoid the lazy copying the vector class does by default, and thus avoid the above compiler errors.  But my usage of this struct does not need performance, so instead making it use `shared_ptr<>` with its copy semantics accomplishes everything I need.